# Xvfb: keyboard error

Tags: centos, xvfb

We have some GUI tests (selenium) that are run on a virtualized `CentOS6.6` environment and when the Xvfb process is started, we get the following error:

```
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86AudioMicMute
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
```

Some tests fail and those tests are related to keyboard shortcuts. Since this warning/error message mentions keyboard, I am quite convinced the failing tests must be caused by this warning message.

Any suggestsions?